# Is "n-th year of relationship" a common phrase?

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms

Example sentence:

> And so, when Katsumi and Kiyoshi reached their **second year of
>   relationship,** they moved in to a one-bedroom apartment.

Is this kind of expression common? If not, what's a more typical alternative?

Comment: Alternatively, you could say "reached their second year together".

Comment: Sound very formal;  "*...had been seeing each other for a year, ...*" perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, albeit with slightly different grammar. The following is a more common way of expressing it:

> And so, when Katsumi and Kiyoshi reached the second year of their relationship, they moved in to a one-bedroom apartment.